# My flutter Svg looks crispy and i dont know how to fix it

Tags: flutter, svg

I am using the package flutter_svg: ^0.22.0 to display svg logo, the reason i chose svg was because i wanted it to be able to scale to different screens, but when i uploaded it, it looks crispy, i need it to look smooth like when i open the SVG file with Chrome

here's my code:

```
  Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 10 / 100,
                child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                              30 /
                              100,
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                          child: Container(
                              width:
                                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                      10 /
                                      100,
                              height:
                                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                      10 /
                                      100,
                              child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                'assets/images/logo.svg',
                                semanticsLabel: 'User Id',
                              ))),
                    ]))
```

HERE IS THE CRISPY IMAGE BELOW, HOW DO I FIX THIS

[image: Crispy Image(NOT OKAY)]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to remove `container` which it is the widget you wrapped SVG. After that give it height and width in `SVG.asset`